# Installing Apache/2.4.37 on centos getting Error

Tags: linux, apache

I have been trying to install Apache/2.4.37 webserver on centos 8 machine and keep getting the following error

Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

```
[root@localhost draj]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-04-13 17:07:09 +0545; 4min 10s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 14004 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14004 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

Apr 13 17:07:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 13 17:07:09 localhost.localdomain httpd[14004]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 122 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Apr 13 17:07:09 localhost.localdomain httpd[14004]: DocumentRoot '/var/www/html' is not a directory, or is not readable
Apr 13 17:07:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 13 17:07:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 13 17:07:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Could somebody kindly shed some light on how to fix this problem, thanks !!

Comment: `DocumentRoot '/var/www/html' is not a directory, or is not readable`

Comment: yes thanks,plz elaborate, have to create a directoy html ?

Comment: Did you check that `/var/www/html` exists and is a directory ? If so, does the permission allow apache to read it ?

Comment: [root@localhost draj]# cd /var/www/html
bash: cd: /var/www/html: No such file or directory
[root@localhost draj]# 
This is what I get

Comment: [root@localhost draj]# cd /var
[root@localhost var]# cd /www
bash: cd: /www: No such file or directory
[root@localhost var]#

Comment: this is the [root@localhost draj]# vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf                                                       122 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
123 
124 #
125 # Relax access to content within /var/www.
126 #
127 <Directory "/var/www">
128     AllowOverride None
129     # Allow open access:
130     Require all granted
131 </Directory>
132 
133 # Further relax access to the default document root:
134 <Directory "/var/www/html">